# Scroll to next element in niceScroll using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, nicescroll

I am using nice-scroll. When I scroll a div, it should scroll to next element of multiple same div with multiple element

Scroll should be up and down; if element there is no next element, scrolling should stop. Also, there are multiple divs with the same name so it may be too complex for me to manage that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".detail-box").niceScroll({cursorborder:"",cursorcolor:"#00F",boxzoom:true});
  });
```

```css
.detail-box{float:left; width: calc(25% - 20px); padding:10px; height:550px; overflow:hidden;}
.detail-box .mid-box{margin:8px 0px; background:#c7c7c7;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/wp-content/plugins/jnicescroll/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

<div class="detail-box">
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="detail-box">
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="detail-box">
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="detail-box">
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mid-box">
  <h1>Jay Khatri</h1>
  <p>Web Designer</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you need to use the jQuery function `.next()`. Here is a example that will automatically scroll to the next element with a certain **CSS** class. 
This is exactly what you are trying to accomplish I believe.

http://jsfiddle.net/UaGjs/9/

```
var next;
$('.next').click(function() {
   if ( next === undefined ) {
     next = $('.mid-box').next();
   } else {
      next = next.next();   
   }
   $(".mid-box").niceScroll({cursorborder:"",cursorcolor:"#00F",boxzoom:true});
});
```

Comment: Thanx for answer

but i want that for OnScroll with using niceScroll

Comment: There you go! :)